# Npm audit report says '1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated' / .Node js

Tags: npm, npm-audit

Firstly, I got this message below when running `npm audit`:

> ```
> updated 1 package and audited 381 packages in 1.767s
> found 1 moderate severity vulnerability
>   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
> → weatherApp npm audit
>
>                       === npm audit security report ===
>
> ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │                               Manual Review                                │
> │           Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve           │
> │                                                                            │
> │         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance        │
> └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
>
> ┌───────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │ Moderate      │ Denial of Service                                          │
> ├───────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ Package       │ axios                                                      │
> ├───────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ Patched in    │ >=0.18.1                                                   │
> ├───────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ Dependency of │ nominatim-geocoder                                         │
> ├───────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ Path          │ nominatim-geocoder > axios                                 │
> ├───────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/880                           │
> └───────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
>
> found 1 moderate severity vulnerability in 381 scanned packages
>   1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
> → weatherApp █
> ```

Typing `npm audit fix` didn't help neither:

> ```
> fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 381 scanned packages
> 1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
> ```

On [https://npmjs.com/advisories/880](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/880) they recommended to upgrade `axios` version to `>=0.18.1`. However, in my `package.json` the version is `^0.19.0`.

**package.json**:

```json
...
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19.0",
  "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
  "ejs": "^3.0.1",
  "epxress": "0.0.1-security",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.1",
  "nominatim-geocoder": "^0.1.4",
  "request": "^2.88.0"
}
...
```

So, I tried to manually upgrade the version of `axios` in the `package-lock.json` as it still shows `0.16.1`.

**package-lock.json**:

```json
"nominatim-geocoder": {
  "version": "0.1.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/nominatim-geocoder/-/nominatim-geocoder-0.1.4.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-7o8I+CZq0tL5zYfdQhzCdmtRF78=",
  "requires": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "lru": "^3.1.0",
    "promise-queue": "^2.2.3",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": {
      "version": "0.16.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.16.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-uk+S8XFn37q0CYN4VFS5rBScPG0=",
      "requires": {
        "follow-redirects": "^1.2.3",
        "is-buffer": "^1.1.5"
      }
```

... to version `0.19.0`. However, that didn't help... Any suggestions?